# Ошибка в стиле ToggleButton при программном Checked=True

Tags: wpf, xaml

Никак не могу понять в чем ошибка. Я задал стиль c анимацией для ToggleButton в отдельном XAML файле который подключил к окну.

Всё работет без ошибок если ToggleButton имеет Checked=False.
Если ToggleButton иммет Checked=True, то вылезает ошибка: *Не удается найти имя "ToggleBorder" в области имен "System.Windows.Controls.ControlTemplate.*

Если програмно задать ToggleButton Checked=True, то появляется ошибка.

Код стиля:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Viewbox>
                    <Border x:Name="ToggleBorder" CornerRadius="10"
                        Background="#FFFFFFFF"
                        Width="40" 
                        Height="20">
                        <Border.Effect>
                            <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0.5" Direction="0" Opacity="0.3" />
                        </Border.Effect>
                        <Ellipse x:Name="ToggleEllipse" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Stretch="Uniform"
                             Margin="2 1 2 1"
                             Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="0.2"
                             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <Ellipse.Effect>
                                <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="10" ShadowDepth="1" Opacity="0.3" Direction="-45" />
                            </Ellipse.Effect>
                        </Ellipse>
                    </Border>
                </Viewbox>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Checked">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ToggleBorder"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                To="#FF4CD661"
                                                Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                                <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ToggleEllipse"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"
                                                    To="20 1 2 1"
                                                    Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Unchecked">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ToggleBorder"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                To="White"
                                                Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                                <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ToggleEllipse"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"
                                                    To="2 1 2 1"
                                                    Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```